# Reading, editing, then saving a library

Tags: swift

Fairly new to swift and I have no idea how I can alter the library, then save the values for the next time I open the app.

Does anyone have an easy way to do this?
I've also added the code down below to give you an idea of what the code looks like.

Thanks in advance!

```
struct Storage: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let category: Int
    let item: String
    let amount: Int
}

struct List {
    
    static let vareStorage = [
        Storage(
            category: 0,
            item: "Kegs",
            amount: 25
        ),
        Storage(
            category: 0,
            item: "Whine",
            amount: 20
        ),
        Storage(
            category: 1,
            item: "Coke",
            amount: 15
        ),
        Storage(
            category: 1,
            item: "Pepsi",
            amount: 10
        ),
        Storage(
            category: 2,
            item: "Napkins",
            amount: 5
        ),
        Storage(
            category: 2,
            item: "Glasses",
            amount: 0
        )
    ]
}
```

Comment: `...how I can alter the library..`, what library are you talking about? P.S, do not call your struct `List`, SwiftUI has already a `List` struct, it may create problems. Look-up `CoreData` to save your data until the next time you open the App. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata

Comment: Research `Codable` for saving your data as json to file

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're asking is how to modify your compiled code (where you have these constants defined) so that the next time the code is run, you have the new values of the constants. While this might be *technically* possible, it is **strongly** discouraged.

Instead, you should use something like [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) or [Realm](https://realm.io), which will take care of storing the values for you.